What are the remedies of kaal sharpa Dosha?
How can one pacify the kaal sharpa dosha in his horoscope. Which deities and mantras can be used to pacify the dosha? Can this be rectified inside our house or does one have to go to a temple? Thank you

Kalasarpa dosha is not mentioned in any Hindu astrological classics written in sanskrit. It is created much later, most probably  by tamil astrologers. So in sastra there is no remedy, because the dosha itself does not exist!
